# Checking For Cookie Right After Setting Cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to check if a cookie `isset` right after I `setcookie`.  It works but I have to reload the page before the correct php file is loaded.

**This is how I'm doing it:**

```
//set cookie
$cookie_value = "Cookie";
setcookie("Placed", $cookie_value, time()+86400);

//check if cookie is set
if (isset($_COOKIE['Placed'])) {
include("display.php");
} else {
include("nodisplay.php");
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: `setcookie` doesn't update the `$_COOKIE` array itself. That's only populated *once* when PHP processes an incoming request.

Comment: Is there a reason as to why you're using cookie instead of session for PHP?

Comment: @dee in the past i had issues with sessions and mobile browsers

Comment: @dee is there a way to set a php session to be valid for 24 hours?